# Nested if-else statements with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, sharepoint, if-statement

So, what I'm doing is that I'm retrieving information from a SharePoint Site. However, when I'm trying to get an item from the site. I'm getting this error:

> Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison,
>   cast the left hand side to type 'string'

It does get the information correctly, however what I want to achieve is a color format wherein when the `Status ="Completed"`, the color will be blue, and if the `Status="Not Completed"` then it'll be red.

```
foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
{
    if (item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"] != null)
    {
        str.AppendLine("<tr><td bgcolor='#E7E7E7'> " + item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"].ToString() + "</td>");

    }
    else if (item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"] == "Completed")
    {
        str.AppendLine("<td bgcolor='#0000FF'> </td>");
    }
    else if (item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"] == "Not Completed")
    {
        str.AppendLine("<td bgcolor='#FF0000'> </td>");
    }      
}
```

Comment: You're getting the error because `item[key]` is an `object` at compile time but you're comparing it to a string. A simple fix is to do this `if (item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"].ToString() == "Completed")`. But you say that it gets the information correctly anyway, so what's the actual problem?

Comment: @keyboardP - post that as an answer

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel - Seems to be the issue OP is facing. Posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because `item[key]` is an object at compile time but you're comparing it to a string. A simple fix is to convert the `item[key]` to a string.

```
if (item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"] != null)
{
    str.AppendLine("<tr><td bgcolor='#E7E7E7'> " + item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"].ToString() + "</td>");
}
else if (item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"].ToString() == "Completed")
{
    str.AppendLine("<td bgcolor='#0000FF'> </td>");
}
else if (item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"].ToString() == "Not Completed")
{
    str.AppendLine("<td bgcolor='#FF0000'> </td>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

keyboardP's way is the correct was to fix the error. But if it's nested like this:

```
if (item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"] != null)
{
    str.AppendLine("<tr><td bgcolor='#E7E7E7'> " + item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"].ToString() + "</td>");
}
else if (item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"].ToString() == "Completed")
{
    str.AppendLine("<td bgcolor='#0000FF'> </td>"); // will never be reached
}
else if (item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"].ToString() == "Not Completed")
{
    str.AppendLine("<td bgcolor='#FF0000'> </td>"); //neither
}
```

The 2 other appendLines will never be reached, because:

```
item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"].ToString() == "Completed"
```

can only be true, if this is also true:

```
item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"] != null
```

which also applies to the original code.
So use this:

```
object obj = item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"];
if ( obj != null)
{
    string value = obj.ToString();
    if (value == "Completed")
    {
       str.AppendLine("<td bgcolor='#0000FF'> </td>"); 
    }
    else if (value == "Not Completed")
    {
       str.AppendLine("<td bgcolor='#FF0000'> </td>"); 
    }  
    else
    {
       str.AppendLine("<tr><td bgcolor='#E7E7E7'> " + value + "</td>");
    }
}
```

This assumes you don't want to do anything, if the Status is not set:

Answer (score -1):

```
if (item["ows_BM_x0020_Status"].ToString() != null)
{}
```

I believe you have to cast the item you search for by index or value to string.

Comment: If the object is null, calling ToString() on it will give a NullReferenceException.